# multiple row insert in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I use multiple row insert syntax in oracle SQL like this:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO student(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE)  VALUES(4,'test_name','test_lname',17)
  INTO student(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE)  VALUES(5,'test_name2','test_lname2',20)
  INTO student(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE)  VALUES(6,'test_name3','test_lname3',21)
  select * from dual;
```

can anyone explain me what is the meaning of using

> select * from dual

at the and of statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it the syntax for `INSERT ALL`

```
INSERT ALL
INTO <table_name> VALUES <column_name_list)
INTO <table_name> VALUES <column_name_list)
...
<SELECT Statement>;
```

if there is nothing you want to select after inserting you do `select * from dual`

otherwise you do your select you want usually to confirm the insert success

[reference](http://psoug.org/snippet/INSERT-ALL_589.htm)

Comment: @Davit khaburdzania your question was whats the meaning of using  `select * from dual ` in the end of the insert statment not what is `select * from dual ` is ?! i think my answer is suitable to your question ! right?

Comment: yes my question was what is the meaning of using select * from dual.
and if syntax of using insert all is so i get it.
but why should i always select something after inserting something?

Comment: because the syntax of using it is requiring selecting something and if you dont want to select somthing you have to `select * from dual` and it will return one empty row its just how it is!

Answer (score 4):

> The DUAL table is a special one-row table present by default in all
>   Oracle database installations. It is suitable for use in selecting a
>   pseudocolumn such as SYSDATE or USER. The table has a single
>   VARCHAR2(1) column called DUMMY that has a value of 'X'.

More about this [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dual.html) and [here](http://psoug.org/snippet/INSERT-ALL_589.htm).

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible, without any tricks, using Database 23c.

```
create table if not exists NEW_OLD_DEMO (
   ID       number
      generated by default as identity ( start with 1 cache 20 )
   , NAME   varchar2(50)
   , SALARY number
);

alter table NEW_OLD_DEMO add constraint NEW_OLD_DEMO_PK primary key ( ID )
   using index;
    
insert into NEW_OLD_DEMO (NAME, SALARY)
values ('Smitty', 10),
        ('Kristopher', 20 ),
        ('Larry', 30);
```

And querying the data back out -

[image]

Docs:

- [23c New Features Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/nfcoa/application-development.html#GUID-DDB05DA1-42A8-4241-B22A-64AD2F46B90A)
- [23c SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html#GUID-C7961CB3-8F60-47E0-96EB-BDCF5DB1317C)

Not that you're limited to passing 65535 entries via the VALUES clause. Also, this will be done as a single transaction.

And this wouldn't be a good answer for Oracle w/o a reference to the [oracle-base example](https://oracle-base.com/articles/23c/table-values-constructor-23c#insert) for using this feature, across insert, merge, with, and select.